# How can I make the text cursor in X Windows easier to see?

Tags: gnome, themes, text, accessibility, cursor

The text cursor in X Windows is too thin for me to see easily. It would be great if I could make the text cursor wider so that it was more visible.

I know how to change the size of the mouse cursor in X by going to System > Preferences > Appearance and customizing the Pointer so that it is larger. But I have not been able to find any setting that allows me to alter the appearance of the text cursor.

So how can I make the text cursor easier to see?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [Gursormaker](http://gursormaker.sourceforge.net/) to edit one of the existing cursor themes from `/usr/share/icons` to make the "xterm" cursor more visible, then export it to an X11 cursor theme.  Place the theme directory in `~/.local/share/icons`.  You should then be able to select it as a cursor theme.

Comment: geekosaur, is "xterm" not one of the mouse cursors? I'm looking to change the text cursor that appears in text windows, input boxes, and terminal windows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "xterm" is the name of the cursor; the same cursor is used for all of those.  Ask the freedesktop folks why they called it "xterm" instead of "text"; it surprised me when I saw it, too.